# dataset to json with schema?

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have an input xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="MA_ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="MA_CODE" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="MA_CODE_P" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <Table1>
    <MA_ID />
    <MA_CODE>PA15TX0009707</MA_CODE>
    <MA_CODE_P>PA15TX0009707001</MA_CODE_P>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <MA_ID />
    <MA_CODE>0</MA_CODE>
    <MA_CODE_P>PA15TX0009707001</MA_CODE_P>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <MA_ID />
    <MA_CODE>1</MA_CODE>
    <MA_CODE_P>PA15TX0009707001</MA_CODE_P>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

and I convert it into a dataset and return string json to client

```
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlPath, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
    string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

after some business(calc and change data), client returns the json string that changed the data and I have to convert that json back to xml original form. 
I used the following way to convert:

```
     DataSet myDataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsondata); 
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     myDataSet.WriteXml(sw, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
     string result = sw.ToString();
```

I got the results, but all elements `xs:element` which have data type number (int, short, decimal... ) that are converted to long, example :

```
<xs:element name="MA_CODE" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" /> 
 === type changed ====> <xs:element name="MA_CODE" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
```

So how can I keep the original formatting when exporting to xml file ?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava: i need keep type of element, not keep the xml beauty

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360133/how-to-serialize-object-to-json-with-type-info-using-newtonsoft-json) help?

Comment: That only helped me to get type  of the input object (in my case is dataset) which will be convert to json, not the data type of each column