# Serialize/Deserialize Object with each field type preserved of an object

Tags: c#, json.net

I am writing a utility, which reads a text file (json) and constructs a json object dynamically and send it to REST API. To achieve this, I want my serialized json object (which I have created using Json.Net in C#) to also preserve type information of each field along with its value.

For example, I want my json file to be in in similar format:

```
{
    "fieldString": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "my custom string data"
    },
    "fieldTimeStamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "value": "2018-12-10T08:25:55.150Z"
    },
    "fieldNumber": {
        "type": "number",
        "value": 999999.999
    },
    "fieldGeopoint": {
        "type": "geopoint",
        "value": {
            "_latitude": 0.0,
            "_longitude": 0.0
        }
    },
}
```

Thanks to questions asked by community members, here is the additional information, I hope this will help...

My utility will be data upload utility, which will read data independent of any application. This will read the data from json file and construct a right object to call the REST API (any). for example, GeoPoint object, it is not a primitive data type and different languages may have different name, attributes associated with this object.

The tool which is creating a json file, will have responsibility of providing typed information along with the field value for each object. My data upload utility will decide how to interpret that GeoPoint to pass it to other API, for example, in Azure CosmosDB, geo-point is referred as "Point" whereas in Good world it is referred as "GeoPoint", others may have different name for the same underlying information. Or for example, some may differentiate between "int" and "float" and other may not.

Comment: Why would `fieldArray` not actually be an array.....  Also is there a question here?

Comment: So... what's stopping you? (besides the fact that it's probably a bad idea - json should contain data, the types belong in a json schema)

Comment: Thanks Erik, its my bad, Array will be default Json array type only.

Comment: @ZoharPeled my utility will be data upload utility, which will read work independent of any application. This will read the data from json file and construct a right object to call the REST API (any). for example, GeoPoint object, it is not a primitive data type and different languages may have different name, attributes associated with this object.

Comment: where do you get the type names from? how would an unknown language know how to use the data of type `geopoint`, or `number` for that matter? also, if we are going down this road - the geopoint has latitude and longitude but they don't have types... you will have to do this recursively for complex objects and it's going to be hell to deserialize.

Comment: @ZoharPeled the tool which is creating a json file, will have responsibility of providing typed information along with the field value for each object. My data upload utility will decide how to interpret that GeoPoint to pass it to other API, for example, in Azure CosmosDB, geo-point is referred as "Point" whereas in Good world it is referred as "GeoPoint", others may have different name for the same underlying information. Or for example, some may differentiate between "int" and "float" and other may not.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, what I'm trying to explain is that the types are not a part of the data. You should generate a json schema to specify the types, and a json to specify the values. This is the standard way of expressing types in json - and for a good reason to. Imagine for a minute you are going to need 1,000 different data entries with the same structure. Using your idea, you will have to specify the data type for each data point in each data entry, meaning repeating the type information 1,000 times. Using a json schema means you only specify the types in one place. [to be continued...]

Comment: Another advantage of using a json schema is that you can use it to validate the json outputs - if the data is corrupt in some way, it will not pass the schema validation. Also, this means that whoever is using your json can simply auto-generate the data structure to deserialize the data from the json, making your service that much easier to use.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks, and I agree. Let me have a look at json schema. Don't know by why I missed this point. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I needed similar thing for returning values with our own flexible data types. I have created a property (metadata) class and put both the internal data type and its serialized data into its properties and serialized that metadata object array as the properties of the requested object.

Answer (score 0):

This is already an ability built into the JSON.Net serializer:

[How to serialize object to json with type info using Newtonsoft.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360133/how-to-serialize-object-to-json-with-type-info-using-newtonsoft-json)

I believe you can leverage this: the difference is actually between a primitive type and object type. If you have an object property it would be supported, if it's a primitive type (perhaps not). So you would need to create a separate class for each primitive type. You would create your own String object, Date object, Number object and more (on the C# side).

Also, you could just use the JsonWriter/JsonReader directly. They're not too hard to use, and will give you the best control over your protocol. The direct code will make it easy to debug, and it will also have a side-effect of performing very well. (Usually, JSON.net uses reflection and/or runtime compiled helper classes)

Comment: This should have been a close vote. You should know that with over 10k reputation points.

Comment: I have never read the rules, and I'm not interested in them. I'm just a coder who asks questions and answers them. Often the rules work against coders, the community, and the culture.

Comment: Hello @Todd,  Thanks, I have gone through this post, but my question is bit different, what I am looking for is a type information at the property lavel of the class object, however in this what I get is the Type info at the object level. until I am missing any other setting.

Comment: @Ravi Oh I see, yes that would be the normal treatment. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am going with Json Schema path as suggested by @ZoharPeled.

But as suggested by [@Todd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53993665/6943737), I have created a following solution which preserves the object type info of a field while serializing the object. I am putting it here just for reference purpose, just in case someone wants to refer it.

```
    class TypeInfoConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var converters = serializer.Converters.Where(x => !(x is TypeInfoConverter)).ToArray();
            JToken jToken = JToken.FromObject(value);
            JObject jObject;
            switch (jToken.Type)
            {
                case JTokenType.Object:
                case JTokenType.Array:
                case JTokenType.Bytes:
                case JTokenType.Date:
                    jObject = JObject.FromObject(new Converter(value));
                    jObject.WriteTo(writer, converters);
                    break;
                default:
                    //jObject = JObject.FromObject(new Converter(value));
                    //jObject.WriteTo(writer);
                    jToken.WriteTo(writer);
                    break;
            }
        }

        class Converter
        {
            public Dictionary<string, object> _attr = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            public object value;

            public Converter(object value)
            {
                this.value = value;
                addAttributes();
            }

            private void addAttributes()
            {
                Type t = value.GetType();
                _attr["type"] = t.Name;

                if (t.IsGenericType
                    && (value is IList || value is IDictionary))
                {
                    collectionAttributes(value, _attr, t);
                }
                else if (t.IsEnum)
                {
                    _attr["type"] = "enum";
                    _attr["class"] = t.Name;
                    //attributes["meaning"] = value.ToString();
                }
            }

            private void collectionAttributes(object value, Dictionary<string, object> attr, Type type)
            {

                Dictionary<string, object> o = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                if (value is IDictionary && value.GetType().IsGenericType)
                {
                    attr["type"] = "map";
                    attr["key"] = type.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name;
                    if(type.GetGenericArguments()[1].IsGenericType == true)
                    {
                        collectionAttributes(((IDictionary)value).Values, o, type.GetGenericArguments()[1]);
                        attr["value"] = o;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        attr["value"] = type.GetGenericArguments()[1].Name;
                    }
                }
                else if (value is ICollection && type.IsGenericType)
                {
                    attr["type"] = "array";
                    if (type.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsGenericType == true)
                    {
                        collectionAttributes(value, o, type.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
                        attr["value"] = o;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        attr["of"] = type.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

usage

```
class TrialObject
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeInfoConverter))]
        public String szObject = "trial string";

        [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeInfoConverter))]
        public Double doubleObject = 999999999.999;

        [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeInfoConverter))]
        public Boolean boolObject = true;

        [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeInfoConverter))]
        public DateTime dateObject = DateTime.Now;

        [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeInfoConverter))]
        public GeoPoint geoPointObject = new GeoPoint() { Latitude = 123456789.123456, Longitude = 123456789.123456 };

        [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeInfoConverter))]
        public Dictionary<string, string> mapObject = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeInfoConverter))]
        public Dictionary<string, List<GeoPoint>> mapObjectEx = new Dictionary<string, List<GeoPoint>>()
            {{ "1", new List<GeoPoint>() { new GeoPoint() { Latitude = 0.0, Longitude = 0.0 } } }};

        [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeInfoConverter))]
        public List<GeoPoint> points = new List<GeoPoint>()
            { new GeoPoint() { Latitude=0.0, Longitude=0.0 } };

        [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeInfoConverter))]
        public Rating rating = Rating.Good;
    }

    class GeoPoint
    {
        public double Latitude;
        public double Longitude;
    }

    enum Rating
    {
        Good,
        Bad,
    }
```