# How to serialize/deserialize an ArrayList and properties that are of an Object type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

how can I get the same object types when I deserialize a json object? The ArrayList is lost and deserialized to an object array and the rectangle is completely lost.

Edit: I cannot change the object types, the payload has to be of type object and I won't know what's in it. I added just 1 example of data contained within but it will vary.

```
  public static void Run()
  {
     Int32 retval = 0;
     ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

     list.Add(retval);
     list.Add(new Rectangle(1, 1, 1, 1));

     Bar bar = new Bar()
     {
        MessageType = Bar.MessageTypes.Msg1,
        Payload = list
     };
     Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
     {
        TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto
     };

     var json1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bar);
     var temp1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bar>(json1);

     var json2 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(bar);
     var temp2 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Bar>(json2);

  }

  public class Bar
  {
     public enum MessageTypes
     {
        Msg1 = 1,
        Msg2 = 2
     }

     public MessageTypes MessageType { get; set; }
     public Object Payload { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "getting the same objects" ? Of course you never get the same objects, you construct new ones, you are creating a deep clone. Since this is intended to happen on two different computers, there is not even the possibility of a different behaviour.
If something is lost in transfer, check your string, is it lost when written to the string, or on the way from the string loaded back to memory ?

Comment: I said same object types not instances, the types are lost

Comment: You don't lose anything, not sure what you mean with "getting the same object".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize object to json with type info using Newtonsoft.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360133/how-to-serialize-object-to-json-with-type-info-using-newtonsoft-json)

Comment: A List, an Array, an Arraylist, or generally collection has only one representation in JSON. And of course you can change the object types, its a text file, the text file is defined by one side. If one side puts an array in, the other gets a list out - that's OK, that's the entire idea behind xml/json. The Text is fixed - nothing else, not the object types. You can also save an int and load a long, if you like. Usually you don't even use the same language, one end runs PHP the other end C#. So what now ?

Comment: @Holger that makes sense why json works the way that it does but it just simply  won't for my scenario without many changes because I'm trying to bridge old code to new code

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's possible, it looks like a custom serializer/deserializer, I will have to take a closer look, I just assumed that there would be an built in option to the core api that would be able to handle this

Comment: @Medic. That's a good idea, enjoy your free choice of types for your new code.
You get in a conflict only, if you do not bridge calls via json only, but also still share old source code, from old to new. Then it is bad design. If you take old and new like independent systems, talking only via kind of SOAP interface, you would not have the need of special types. It's a perfect way to migrate from ArrayList to `List<T>` without changing the old code, just with writing the new one. Why having new code with obsolete types ? Sounds halfhearted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use soap serialization instead as it adds the types into the xml

```
  using System;
  using System.Text;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
  using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;

  namespace Utils
  {
     public class XMLUtil
     {
        public static Byte[] StringToUTF8ByteArray(String xmlString)
        {
           return new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(xmlString);
        }

        public static String SerializeToXML<T>(T objectToSerialize)
        {
           using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
           using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
           {
              SoapFormatter soapFormatter = new SoapFormatter();
              soapFormatter.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
              soapFormatter.Serialize(ms, objectToSerialize);
              String decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
              return decoded;
           }
        }

        public static T DeserializeFromXML<T>(string xmlString) where T : class
        {
           T retval = default(T);
           using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(StringToUTF8ByteArray(xmlString)))
           {
              SoapFormatter soapFormatter = new SoapFormatter();
              soapFormatter.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
              retval = soapFormatter.Deserialize(stream) as T;
           }
           return retval;
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't deserialize because it is not aware of the types it needs to serialize to. 
Don't use an ArrayList, try to specify the properties of your payload . Something like this should work:

```
public enum MessageTypes
{
    Msg1 = 1,
    Msg2 = 2
}

public class PayLoad
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public Rectangle Rectangle { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public MessageTypes MessageType { get; set; }
    public PayLoad Payload { get; set; }
}
```